# Divisibility of $(x+y)^n-(x-2y)^n$

Tags: number-theory

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Let $f(n)$ be the largest integer such that there exists a polynomial $p\in\mathbb{Z}[x, y]$ such that
$$
(x+y)^n-(x-2y)^n=3^{f(n)}p.
$$
What is the formula for $f(n)$? I think it is $v_3(n)+1$ where $v_3$ is the $3$-adic valuation.

Comment: Why do you make that guess? Thru trial and error, or is it a heuristic you have? Either way you should share your thoughts with us

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is so. First of all, the coefficient in $x^{n-1}y$ is $3\binom n1=3n$, and the power of three is $1+v_3(n)$. Let us show that all other coefficients are also divisible by $3$ to the power $1+v_3(n)$. For this, let $3^a$ be the exact power of $3$ dividing $n$, where $a\in\{0,1,2,3\dots\}$. We write 
$$n = 3^aN\ ,\qquad (N,3)=1\ .$$
Let $k$ be among $1,2,3\dots n$. We write similarly
$$k = 3^bK\ ,\qquad (K,3)=1\ .$$
Then let us consider the corresponding coefficient
$$
\begin{aligned}
\binom nk\cdot(1-(-2)^k)
&=
\binom nk\cdot(1-(1-3)^k)
\\
&=\frac
{\color{red}n(n-1)\dots(n-k+1)}
{\color{red}k(k-1)\dots1}
\cdot
\left(\ 3^1\binom k1
-3^2\binom k2
+\dots
\right)\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\color{red}n$ contributes with $3^a$,
so it is enough to show that the $3$-valuation of 
$$
\frac 1{\color{red}k}
\cdot
\left(\ \binom k1
-3^1\binom k2
+\dots
\right)
$$
is $\ge 0$. So let us consider one of the terms in the parenthesis, it contains some $\binom kj$, and we write
$$j = 3^cJ\ ,\qquad (J,3)=1\ .$$
The corresponding coefficient is then
$$
\frac 1{\color{red}k}\cdot 3^{j-1}\cdot\binom kj
=
\frac{3^{j-1}}j\binom{k-1}{j-1}\ .
$$
And it is clear that $j-1\ge c$.